# Can´t detect 5ghz network Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, network-manager, broadcom

My computer can´t detect a 5GHz network I installed in my apartment. I think my wireless adapter can´t support this frecuency because when I run the command

```
iwlist wlp2s0 freq
```

this is the output:

```
wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
```

My computer has a Broadcom BCM43142 802.11b/g/n wireless adapter.

UPDATE

This is what I get when I run sudo iwlist scan:

```
wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: CC:40:D0:60:EB:C4
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TangoIndia_2.4"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000E54616E676F496E6469615F322E34
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEC0117FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080100000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080100000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B10
                    IE: Unknown: DD880050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700101EC0E0A01E6A935E3BA71CBD8033DE2D1021000D4E4554474541522C20496E632E10230006455833373030102400064558333730301042000D34414D453835374641303241381054000800060050F20400011011000645583337303010080002218C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4307000000
          Cell 02 - Address: 78:8A:20:57:A2:F7
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"meiexien"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00086D6569657869656E
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 0B050300920000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC011BFFFFFF0000000000000000000100000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601080C00000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD1300156D00010100010237E58106788A2056A2F7
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: 78:8A:20:57:A5:22
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"meiexien"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00086D6569657869656E
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0501008E0000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC011BFFFFFF0000000000000000000100000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601080C00000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD1300156D00010100010237E58106788A2056A522
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: FC:EC:DA:32:8E:B0
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"meiexien"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00086D6569657869656E
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 0B050100500000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC011BFFFFFF0000000000000000000100000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606080C00000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD1300156D00010100010237E58106FCECDA318EB0
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: FE:EC:DA:32:8E:B0
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0000
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 050402030000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0500003B0000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC011BFFFFFF0000000000000000000100000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606080C00000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD1800156D00010128010237E58106FCECDA318EB08201008300
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: E4:AA:5D:2D:4E:D2
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=28/70  Signal level=-82 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"eduroam"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0007656475726F616D
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B0C12961824
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1E
                    IE: Unknown: 0B050100B48D5B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC191BFFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F06001000000140
                    IE: Unknown: 851E0D008F000F00FF03590043412D41502D313634000000000000000100004E
                    IE: Unknown: 9606004096001600
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD06004096010104
                    IE: Unknown: DD050040960305
                    IE: Unknown: DD050040960B09
                    IE: Unknown: DD050040961401

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Comment: Does it appear in: `sudo iwlist scan`? We needn't see the whole list, just the network if it appears. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I would suggest trying channels 36, 40, 44, or 48 on 5GHz

Comment: @chili555 updated the post to show what I get when I run sudo wlist scan.

Comment: @Jeremy31 how can I do that?

Comment: Set your wifi router to one of those channels as I have a suspicion about Broadcom wifi cards in Linux

Comment: No 5 GHz at all, not yours, not the neighbors! Do you know what channel the router is on now? Auto channel select or fixed?

Comment: I don't think that's a dual band card -- the "n" does not imply 5GHz.

Comment: I made some research and find out that my wifi card doesn't support 5GHz. Thank you all.